# Why doesn't this loop work for finding the Euclid sum of vectors?

Tags: c, loops

I am trying to find the Euclidian sum of two vectors (vector1, vector2) that I have already entered into the program. I am trying to do this with a while loop, but for some reason it won't produce the correct result. Would someone be able to show me where I am going wrong with my code? Thank you so much.

```
i = 1;
int sum = 0;
while (i <= n - 1) {
sum = sqrt((vector1[i] - vector2[i])^2);
i++;
}




printf("%d", sum);
```

Comment: Change `sum = ` to `sum += ` I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `sum =` at every iteration of the loop, meaning that by the time the loop ends, `sum` will attain the value computed at the last iteration.

I guess you want to use `sum +=` instead.

Also note that the type of `sum` is `int`, so you'll be losing any floating-point information computed by `sqrt` during the process.

Also note that `a^b` means XOR between `a` and `b`, not `a` to the power of `b`.

In short, this should solve all 3 problems listed above:

```
sum += abs(vector1[i] - vector2[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I am only allowed to use functions in the stdio.h and math.h libraries.

Comment: @learningcomputerscience: I'm pretty sure that `abs` is in `math.h`. If it's not, then you can simply implement it in your own code (something like `return x > y ? x - y : y - x;`).